# Can i use backward compat for save of data Unicode in Room prelollipop version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, backwards-compatibility

1.Can I save utf-16 text in room table using backward compatibility for prelollipop android versions?

```
class Table @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) constructor
@ColumnInfo(name = "datas" ,typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT,collate = ColumnInfo.UNICODE)
```